# Using Autofac with Webforms and .NET 3.5

Tags: autofac

I'm trying to use Autofac with my current application but I'm using the .NET 3.5 and the NuGet package only works with the .NET 4.5.
What is the best (or latest) release that I can use with ASP.NET and .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If my eyes work correctly, [this list](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/list?can=1&q=3.5&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) shows that Autofac 2.6.3.862 is the latest stable release for .NET 3.5.

Comment: Great to know the latest version for .NET 3.5. I don't realize the updated version changed since early this year. To install from Nuget, `PM> Install-Package Autofac -Version 2.6.3.862` like [in here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/2.6.3.862)

Comment: i wonder, if it ok to use older autofac (2.6), when 3.x is out.. i just am not able use net >3.5, unfortunately